# fopen timeout not working

Tags: php, nginx, fopen, http-status-code-503

I am using `fopen` to open a http link. If the link is down/not available the server is loading until I get the error "502 Bad Gateway". If the link is available, then everything is working fine.

To fix the Bad Gateway Error, I'm using `stream_context_create()` Method with timeout but this is not working.

I hope someone can help me to fix this problem :)

My Code:

```
$context = stream_context_create( array( 'http' => array( 'timeout' => 3.0 ) ) );
    $url = "http://localhost:8090/$port.ts";


    $file_handler = fopen( $url, "rb", false, $context ) or exit( "Stream Not Working" );

        foreach ( $http_response_header as $h ) {
        header( $h );
    }

    while ( ! feof( $file_handler ) && ClientConnected() ) {


    $response = stream_get_line( $file_handler, 8192 );
    $bytes += strlen( $response );

    echo $response;
        }
    }
    @fclose( $file_handler );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about testing the URL before trying the file operations?

Comment: If I test the URL before the file operation I get HTTP-Code 200 -> File is reachable.

Comment: @Edit apply only for 5 Minutes :(
If I test the URL before the file operation I get HTTP-Code 200 -> File is reachable.

My URL: http://localhost:8090/$port.ts is a file from ffserver. If the ffserver is running, then the URL exist also but the url contains no content :(